# How to set recyclerView item non clickable but scrolling enable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I implemented a SwipeRefreshLayout using a RecyclerView. I want this because my RecyclerView just shows some small button, within a clickable Cardview.so if sometime set disable click and scrolling enable. try this below code but not working, please help me.
I tried the following Java code:

```
 myRecyclerView.setEnabled(false);
 myRecyclerView.setClickable(false);
```

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical">
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/simpleSwipeRefreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/e_helptoolrecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:longClickable="false"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:stackFromEnd ="true" >
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And also try java file:

```
myRecyclerView .addOnItemTouchListener(new    RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                        return true;
                    }

                   @Override
                    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {


                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                    }

                });
```

this method try it.but some problem whloe Recyclerview disable. my problem is only disable button. Scrolling will be enable.

Comment: can you explain more about it

Comment: Is that button you want to disable is in your Recyclerview  item xml ?

Comment: ill suggest you to do this code for button not the Recyclerview .......means 
yourButton.setEnabled(false);
 yourButton.setClickable(false);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(null);

Comment: My button on Activity. this clickable for recyclerview item buttton disable and enable .

Comment: can you please post your adapter code..........

Comment: Adapter code post please check it. and replay me.

Comment: please help me.